# .aac audio doesn't continue playing in mediasource

Tags: javascript, audio, aac, media-source

I am attempting to stream an `.acc` audio file using the MediaSource API in JavaScript. The problem I'm encountering is that after loading the first partial audio chunk into the media source buffer, the audio starts playing. However, when I try to append another partial chunk to the source buffer, the playback freezes, and I receive an error with the `new Audio()` variable on the second partial playback.

```js
mediaSource.addEventListener("sourceopen", async () => {
  source = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer(chunks.aac.mime); // audio/aac
  
  // first segment of audio buffer
  const arrayBuffer = await fetchDecode(
    chunks.aac.url, //audio url
    chunks.aac.segments()[0] // range bytes of partial
  );

  // adding first partial of audio in source
  source.appendBuffer(arrayBuffer);
  segmentsFetched++;
  chunkDecodedBlock.innerHTML = `Chunks Decoded: ${segmentsFetched}/${
    chunks.aac.segments().length
  }`;

  audio.addEventListener("error", (event) => {
    // this throws error when second partial playback must start but it doesn't
    console.error("Audio element error:", event);
  });
});


//this update buffer runs after clicking play button
const updateBuffer = async () => {
  // if all segmets got fetched stop updateBuffer
  if (segmentsFetched === chunks.aac.segments().length) return;

  // get other segments of audio
  const arrayBuffer = await fetchDecode(
    chunks.aac.url,
    chunks.aac.segments()[segmentsFetched]
  );

  source.appendBuffer(arrayBuffer);
  segmentsFetched++;
};
```

`chunks.aac.segments()[0]` is array of bytes which audio parts should I get

*segments looks like this*

```
[
  [0, 1234],
  [1235, 2323]
  ...
]
```

playback works fine with the mp3 format, I'm encountering a problem during segment transitions. Specifically, there is a noticeable distortion in the audio when transitioning to the next segment. I suspect that this issue might be due to the inherent drawbacks of the mp3 format, given its imperfect structure and lossy compression nature

*this is the error I get on `.aac` playback on second partial*
[image]

Comment: What is your AAC audio wrapped in?  MP4/ISOBMFF?  ADTS?

Comment: @Brad maybe none? im not sure, how should I check it?

Comment: Hmm, how are you encoding the audio?

Comment: @Brad fetching whole audio file from s3 and specifying partial bytes to get segment in arraybuffer and appending it in `MediaSource.addSourceBuffer`

Comment: Ok, but how was the AAC audio file encoded in the first place?

Comment: @Brad for testing I just converted `mp4` to `aac`

Comment: How?  With what?  If you just extracted raw AAC from its container, that isn't going to work.  You'll need to at least use ADTS as a bitstream format.  And, as far as I know even ADTS doesn't work with MediaSource, but I haven't checked that in a couple years ago maybe it does now.